# Insert a comma after first space in string [T-SQL]

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have a field that contains full names like "Last First Middle" with no comma.

I want to put a comma after the last name like "Last, First Middle".

Comment: Why not properly normalize this instead of hacking this in there? When you stuff two values into a single intersection you violate 1NF.

Comment: @SeanLange We get a text file from a 3rd party in that format, and we need to create an output file according to another 3rd party's (4th party's?) requirements, this being one of them. Neither of the other vendors normalize their data. Our tables are simply mirroring the csv text files that get sent to us. And the data will always be accessed by the 4th party's system, never directly from our database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CHARINDEX function to find the first space in the string and then use the STUFF function to stuff a comma in there.

```
DECLARE @FullName as NVARCHAR(50)

SET @FullName = 'Harris Neil Patrick'

SELECT STUFF(@FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', @FullName, 0), 0, ',');
```

returns 'Harris, Neil Patrick'